# connect from helm to kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I have an application that is deployed on kubernetes cluster. Accessing this application using rancher namespace. By specifying this namespace I am getting "get pods", and all information.
Now, this application I want to control from the helm. what do I need to do?
I have installed helm where my kubectl installation is there.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `control` ?

Comment: Have you tried helm init...what error are you getting?

Comment: Control meaning, using helm I should stop instance and start application again.  helm is installed successfully. however how my application will get access by helm ? Lets suppose I have 10 docker images, using rancher I have deployed these dependent images on namespace. Now I am able to access my application. How helm can take control on this application ?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to "control" applications on Kubernetes cluster with Helm, you should start with [helm charts](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/). You can create some if one is not already available. Once you have chart(s), you can target the Kubernetes cluster with the cluster's `KUBECONFIG` file.

If I had a Helm chart like `my-test-app` and a Kubernetes cluster called `my-dev-cluster`.

With Helm I can:

- deploy - `install`

  ```
  helm install test1 my-test-app/ --kubeconfig ~/.kubeconfigs/my-dev-cluster.kubeconfig
  ```
- update - `upgrade`

  ```
  helm upgrade test1 my-test-app/ --kubeconfig ~/.kubeconfigs/my-dev-cluster.kubeconfig
  ```
- remove - `uninstall`

  ```
  helm uninstall test1 my-test-app/ --kubeconfig ~/.kubeconfigs/my-dev-cluster.kubeconfig
  ```

Where `my-dev-cluster.kubeconfig` is the kubeconfig file for my cluster in `~/.kubeconfigs` directory. Or you can set the path using `KUBECONFIG` environment variable.