# Sealed secret on different clusters

Tags: kubernetes, sealedsecret

What is the common way to deploy a chart(which contains sealed secrets) to different clusters?

Because the clusters contains different sealed-secret controller (with different secret key) it seems unfeasible.

Or is there any way to install a sealed-secret controller with the same secret key as the other clusters?

Answer (score 2):

**Sealed Secrets** can be created by anyone but can only be decrypted by the controller where the secrets are created, follow this [**blog**](https://blog.knoldus.com/introduction-to-sealed-secrets-in-kubernetes) authored by Vidushi Bansal for more information. So in order to use **sealed secrets** for multiple kubernetes clusters you need to maintain helm directories or repositories and set the target clusters as described in this [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63485239/connect-from-helm-to-kubernetes-cluster) provided by [seshadri_c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13968097/seshadri-c). Now since these sealed secrets have respective target clusters it will be easy for you to manage multiple clusters.